# How to use React Navigation stackActions reset with Animation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Based on the sample below, it couldn't navigate with animation.

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'MyProfile', params:  { url: 'https://.....' } }),
  ]
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

I couldn't find any docs mentioned about this, If this is not applicable? How can I do custom transition ?

Comment: https://medium.com/async-la/custom-transitions-in-react-navigation-2f759408a053 have you seen this?

Comment: It is not working for React-navigation-3. I think their version all backward incompatibility

Answer (score 0):

From screen3

```
const navigateAction = StackActions.reset({
              index: 1,
              actions: [
                NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' }),
                NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Screen2' }),
              ],
            })
```

this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', navigateAction)